# How to configure Capybara so that the browser sends all requests to localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara

For testing, I do not want the browser talking to any external services. I can mock all the external requests if they are sent to localhost instead of the external services.

Is there a way for Capybara to launch the browser so that it proxies all requests to localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you might try [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy).  It sets up a proxy to capture browser requests and allow you to stub them:

```
proxy.stub('http://example.com/json/').and_return(:json => { :foo => 'bar' })
```

Comment: Actually, I tried puffing-billy. It works great, but does not work with WebMock.

Answer (score 0):

The browser does not like the response from secure requests, but works otherwise.

Create a firefox_profile directory in the spec directory.

Create a `times.json` file in firefox_profile with:

```
{
  "created": 1441059879941
}
```

Then update `spec_helper`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
      profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new('spec/firefox_profile')

      profile["network.proxy.type"] = 1
      profile["network.proxy.http"] = 'localhost'
      profile["network.proxy.http_port"] = 3000
      profile["network.proxy.ssl"]  = "proxy.domain.example.com"
      profile["network.proxy.ssl_port"] = 3000

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: profile)
    end
```